# Gem install problems Mac 10.11.5 ('no implicit conversion of nil into String')

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to do `gem install jekyll` (or github-pages) and nothings working.

```
> rvm install current && rvm use current
ruby-2.3.1
Using /Users/willwade/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1
> gem install jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

I've tried different versions.. e.g. 1.9.3 and its a similar output. E.g.

```
> rvm use 1.9.3
Using /Users/willwade/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
> gem install github-pages
Fetching: terminal-table-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed terminal-table-1.6.0
Fetching: mercenary-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mercenary-0.3.6
Fetching: ffi-1.9.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
Fetching: rb-inotify-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.7
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.7
Fetching: listen-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed listen-3.0.6
Fetching: jekyll-watch-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-1.4.0
Fetching: sass-3.4.22.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.4.22
Fetching: jekyll-sass-converter-1.3.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-1.3.0
Fetching: rouge-1.10.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    can't convert nil into String
```

And I've also tried the system version e.g. with sudo

```
> sudo gem install jekyll
Fetching: liquid-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed liquid-3.0.6
Fetching: kramdown-1.11.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

(Edit) And the same with 2.2.0:

```
> rvm use 2.2.0
Using /Users/willwade/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
> gem install github-pages
Fetching: terminal-table-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed terminal-table-1.6.0
Fetching: mercenary-0.3.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mercenary-0.3.6
Fetching: ffi-1.9.10.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
Fetching: rb-inotify-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-inotify-0.9.7
Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rb-fsevent-0.9.7
Fetching: listen-3.0.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed listen-3.0.6
Fetching: jekyll-watch-1.4.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-watch-1.4.0
Fetching: sass-3.4.22.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.4.22
Fetching: jekyll-sass-converter-1.3.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed jekyll-sass-converter-1.3.0
Fetching: rouge-1.10.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Any ideas on a fix? What this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these approaches:

- Downgrading to a previous gem
- Ensure the pages have no syntax errors
- Ensure that the config file is not blank

Hope one of those helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is causing the headaches.. But this fixes it for me:

1. Reboot the mac.
2. Command + R
3. Open a terminal. Type `csrutil disable`
4. Restart
5. gem install jekyll or sudo.. (i.e. use the system ruby)
6. Repeat steps 1&2 - and type `csrutil enable`

Basically there is a SIP problem with El Capitan and Ruby.See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11